# Reading encrypted NTFS partition on external hard drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, ntfs

I have a hard drive that I intend putting into an external USB casing and connecting to my PC running Windows 7. The hard drive is XP NTFS and recently refused to boot XP and seems to be corrupt. How will I be able to access the encrypted files on this disk - I know the password for the user on it, if that helps?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to solve the XP boot problems, then log on as the user under which the files were encrypted.